# ResourceNotFound error with Pureview API request

Tags: azure, azure-purview

I am trying to use the Microsoft Pureview API and whatever the request I am making i am getting a ResourceNotFound error.

So I build a pureview account, named fhvidev
[image: fhvidev Properties]

The Api endpoint is https://fhvidev.purview.azre.com/catalog,
so I create a Service principal to access it named pureviewap
[image: Pureview app properties]

I granted permission for this app on the whole catalogue of Pureview

[image]

Then I try to access the API using Postman :

Therefore I created an Oauth2 Authentication for the Collection
[image: Postman main description]
I add a resource
[image: Ressource postman]

And generate the token (which seems to be fine )

[image: token]

Now I am trying to make a simple request ( GET https://fhvidev.purview.azure.com/catalog/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs ) to list entityType. then i got the Resource Not found error :
[image]

```
GET /catalog/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: af77ef25-ee88-4084-8ad3-6acef147ace4
Host: fhvidev.purview.azure.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
 
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2022 08:38:41 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-ms-correlation-request-id: eae872d7-2ea4-4fdb-a3d8-c340ac9360a8
 
{"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"Resource not found"}}
```

Any pointer or direction where to look or tutorial whill be greatly appreciate.

Regards

Vincent Diallo-Nort

Answer (score 0):

So I was missing a permission on the app.
Within the app registration panel you need to give permission on the Pureview API. Then the request work.
[image]